# How do I specify fonts for a specific encoding?

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer

I am using flying saucer library and trying to add a custom font for a specific encoding of letters. So that I could make support for unicode characters.

Here is the link of solution that I follow from official guide of flying saucer library *http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_33*.
Below is the code,

```
    public void convertHtmlToPdf(String html, String css, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        html = correctHtml(html);
        html = getFormedHTMLWithCSS(html, css);

        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
        TagNode rootTagNode = cleaner.clean(html);
        CleanerProperties cleanerProperties = cleaner.getProperties();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new PrettyXmlSerializer(cleanerProperties);
        String cleanedHtml = xmlSerializer.getAsString(rootTagNode);

        File fontFile = new File("/Verdana.ttf");
        FontFactory.register(fontFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ITextRenderer r = new ITextRenderer();

        r.getFontResolver().addFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        r.setDocumentFromString(cleanedHtml);

        r.layout();
        r.createPDF(out);
        r.finishPDF();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

But Still I am unable to encode certain characters. Like,

```
'■' : '&#x25a0;',
'▲' : '&#x25b2;',
```

For '■' i am getting &x25a0; in generated pdf, and likewise for other characters that I try to encode.